# I want to better understand the terminology used when importing Express

Tags: node.js, express

When I write:

**const express = require('express');**

**const app = express();**

Why could I not write:

**const app = require('express);**

I understand that Express is a package, but what is happening that prevents me from simply combining those two lines into one? Why does that not work? I know that it doesn't, but I want to be able to explain why.

Comment: Because what is loaded (returned) by require() are _modules_ which, usually, export a default function. When `const app = express()` is executed that function is called. You could `const app = require('express')()` however.

Comment: I get it! When I do "require," it's similar to instantiating a Class that has a default function. I execute that default function when I use "app."

Comment: "require" may be a little confusing if you're thinking of it like PHP in that while I might require "header.php," with Express / Node, when I do "require(express) the result is a function that still has to be called in order for it to perform anything.